# iphone overflow hidden not working when fancybox open

Tags: iphone, fancybox, overflow, hidden

When `Fancybox` opens in `iPhone's Safari browser` :

- I need to stop the background scrolling
- But have scrolling inside `Fancybox.`

The following code does not work in iPhone's Safari browser :

```
helpers: {
   overlay: {
      locked: true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now issue resolved. I have resolved this by adding below code

// Global variable current poisition

currentPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

afterShow: function() {

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {

```
  $(window).scrollTop(currentPosition);
```

});

},

beforeClose: function() {

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

},